# How can I increase my local browser storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have 672.4 GB of available storage as seen in the image below. But when I open Chrome and try to view my available local storage I get much less, about 291MB.

First, how do I clear the 120MB being used?

Second, how do I increase this available storage?

`navigator.storage.estimate().then((data)=>console.log(data))`
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's _browser_ local storage, not all the available storage on your harddrive. There's a setting/privacy option in Chrome where you can clear your cache/site data.

Comment: Please never write an arrow function that looks like `x => f(x)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: @ElectricShadow `.then(console.log)` doesn't work because the `this` binding is wrong, so the arrow function is necessary.

Comment: @ElectricShadow Statements like that should include some reasoning.

Comment: @BenWest If the purpose is to manipulate the `this` binding, then doing it in that way is very obscure. It is much better to use `.then(console.log.bind(this))`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria

Comment: Your browser is a sandbox, meaning when it runs, it allows you limited access to your OS, including memory.

Comment: @ElectricShadow `x => f(x)` is useful sometimes, for example: `const foo = ["bar", "baz"]; foo.forEach((str) => console.log(str));` because `foo.forEach(console.log);` also prints out the `index` and `array` variables that are also passed into a callback function inside of `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: @Samathingamajig You're right. I didn't think of that. I think presetting arguments that don't come first would be the only time when `x => f(x)` would be okay. If the arguments do come first or you need to set the value of `this` to that of the current scope, use `Function.prototype.bind` instead.

Comment: @Andy Any reason why the browser local storage is .01% of my total HD size? Is there any way to increase this?

Comment: @symlink already answered that. For security concerns your local storage size is limited to your browser settings. [This might help your understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Comment: @Andy That refers to the limit per storage item right? Not the total size of the indexeddb?  What browser setting can I change to increase the total size? It should be more than .01% right?